# How to identify what is causing a simple application to crash in Windows? (application compiles successfully in Visual Studio + full error in post)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, compilation

I am using a third-party api and have successfully compiled the below code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "ThirdPartyLibrary.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "ThirdPartyLibrary.lib")

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    const char* version = ThirdPartyLibrary::GetVersion();
    std::cout << version << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

However when I run the executable, a windows with "Hello World!" is displayed and the following notification pops up:[image]

The details section specifies:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: Project1.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    59b75de4
  Fault Module Name:    Project1.exe
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   59b75de4
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00000000000165fd
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 67fc
  Additional Information 2: 67fc46792ce081021880cc23e0b31aa5
  Additional Information 3: 6b65
  Additional Information 4: 6b656a5b6790a11fed1e18ef18753a38

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=280262

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

How to identify what is causing this behaviour?

Comment: Use your debugger.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I assume you mean debugger in Visual Studio? (I am new to C++). What should I be on the lookout for since this is a runtime crash?

Comment: Check the return value from 3rd party dll function before using it. Step-by-step your code in debugger and see the line causing the crash + callstack

Comment: If you have access to the source code of the library step into that method, else read the documentation of library

Comment: If there's a bug indeed that terminates your application unexpectedly in the third party app, and you don't have access to the source code of it, there's nothing really you can do about it.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the source code. Debugger states that `Exception thrown at 0X00007FF7993965FD in Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.`. The api is to communicate with an application on the Desktop, I'm assuming that the application isn't giving me access to it's memory?

Comment: Doesn't look like the crash is happening in the DLL.  My guess would be that GetVersion() is returning a null pointer, and the crash - a null pointer dereference, according to your last comment - occurs when you try to print it.  But if you step through your application using the debugger, you should be able to *see*, one way or the other.

Comment: ... to single-step through your application while in Visual Studio, use F10 ("Step Over") instead of F5 ("Run").

Comment: `const char* version = ThirdPartyLibrary::GetVersion();`line smells very bad to me! Try sthg like `char version[256]; strcpy(version, ThirdPartyLibrary::GetVersion());`

Comment: Please share GetVersion() declaration from .h file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the problem is because the extension is an MFC application which needed to be loaded from the main application.